# Excel copying value of one cell into another based off value of third cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have one cell from a range `(AG2:AG30)` copy the value of another cell from a similar range `(AB2:AB30)` based on the value of a third cell `(D2:D30)`.

- The value for column D is selected from a drop down box and the value of column AB is a formula.
- I don't need to copy the formula into column AG just the value. Values for column D would be `"Surgery"`, `"OR"`, `"ER"`, `"PICU"`, and `"Other"`.

If anyone could help with a vba code that could do this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: My first thought is that you have static cells with a standard IF formula or possibly a CHOOSE  formula instead of VBA.  Maybe if you can add some detail about column D criterion it would become more clear (Sometimes when I'm working in VBA I automatically complicate my task with code when it would simply be a formula in the cell if the task was isolated).

Comment: I am using a nested IF formula in column AG. The criteria for column D is just selected from a data list. I guess a better description of what I'm looking for is this. When I select "Surgery" from column D the value from column AB would copy to column AG, if "OR" is selected in column D then the value of column AB would copy to AH. Moving one column over AI, AJ, AK for each possible value of column D.

Comment: Well, it's possible I'm just too think in the head right now.  If so, my apologies.  Without me better understanding if there is a reason preventing it, I would still say your options would include either your nested IF (or a CHOOSE formula since the dropdown list is defined) or basically VBA code to mimic that, such as SELECT CASE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more of.... exactly what you want :)

Please please comment if you have any questions. I broke it apart for coding clarity and easy customization.

```
Option Explicit

'module-scope variables
Dim range1 As Range
Dim range2 As Range
Dim range3 As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim string1 As String

Dim address1 As String
Dim address2 As String


Sub derp()

'set your sheet here or just let it work on active sheet

Set range1 = Range("AG2:AG30")
Set range2 = Range("AB2:AB30")
Set range3 = Range("D2:D30")

For i = 0 To range3.Rows.Count

    string1 = range3(i).Value
    address1 = range1(i).Address
    address2 = range2(i).Address

    Select Case string1

        Case string1 = "Surgery"
            'do stuff here
            Call Valueswap(address1, address2)

        Case string1 = "OR"


        Case string1 = "ER"

        Case string1 = "PICU"

        Case string1 = "Other"

        Case Else
            'value in column D yields error, put a message here

    End Select

Next







End Sub

Function Valueswap(address1 As String, address2 As String)
    'puts second address value into the first address
    Range(address2).Value = Range(address1).Value

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
=IF(C2=1,B2,A2)
```

IF says that you will display the value of the second parameter if the first parameter is true. Otherwise it will copy the third parameter.

In my example, if C2 is equal to 1, then the function will return B2. Otherwise A2.

Comment: That did work, but only if all values were already in the cells. I guess I would have to make the formula into a macro or a macro button on the worksheet. That can be run after all data is inputted. Thanks!